# В запросе к БД нужно выставить приоритет по дате

Tags: sql, база-данных

```
SELECT
         MAX(VERSION_NUMBER),
         LAG(SCAN_DATE, 0, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SCAN_DATE) AS SCAN_DATE
FROM     HT_ALL_TABLES_INFO
GROUP BY VERSION_NUMBER,
         SCAN_DATE;
```

Есть такой запрос. Он выдает список версий. нужно, чтобы запрос возвращал предыдущую запись и сравнивал по их по времени. Т.е. может быть две версии 35 и 35 но 35 которая выше она имеет такой же номер но другое время.

ут в запросе так же выходят все версии а мне нужно чтобы выдавал 2. т.е. например версия 35 scan_date 17-SEP-19 10.46.05.824000 PM и версия 35 scan_date 20-AUG-19 08.42.35.659000 PM –

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как мне так задать параметры чтобы выходило только 2 последние строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032784/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то так:

```
SELECT
         MAX(VERSION_NUMBER),
         LAG(SCAN_DATE, 0, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SCAN_DATE) AS SCAN_DATE
FROM     HT_ALL_TABLES_INFO
GROUP BY VERSION_NUMBER, SCAN_DATE
ORDER BY VERSION_NUMBER, SCAN_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: Тут в запросе так же выходят все версии а мне нужно чтобы выдавал 2. т.е. например версия 35 scan_date 17-SEP-19 10.46.05.824000 PM и версия 35 scan_date 20-AUG-19 08.42.35.659000 PM