# Как мне так задать параметры чтобы выходило только 2 последние строки

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть запрос. Как мне так задать параметры чтобы выходило только 2 последние строки по версии и времени

```
SELECT
         MAX(VERSION_NUMBER),
         LAG(SCAN_DATE, 0, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SCAN_DATE) AS SCAN_DATE
FROM     HT_ALL_TABLES_INFO
GROUP BY VERSION_NUMBER,
         SCAN_DATE;
```

Comment: Решение зависит от СУБД. Укажите. PS. Для Оракла это `FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY` с сортировкой по убыванию даты.

Comment: Да для оракла..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В запросе к БД нужно выставить приоритет по дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032737/%d0%92-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MAX(VERSION_NUMBER),
    LAG(SCAN_DATE, 0, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SCAN_DATE) AS SCAN_DATE
FROM     HT_ALL_TABLES_INFO
GROUP BY VERSION_NUMBER, SCAN_DATE
ORDER BY SCAN_DATE DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY `SCAN_DATE` DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: Как полностью будет выглядеть ? Вставляю в разные места DESC LIMIT 2 ничего не выходит

Comment: SELECT
         MAX(VERSION_NUMBER),
         LAG(SCAN_DATE, 0, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SCAN_DATE LIMIT 2) AS SCAN_DATE
FROM     HT_ALL_TABLES_INFO
GROUP BY VERSION_NUMBER,
         SCAN_DATE;